# Heart Rate storage

Tags: database, postgresql, doctrine

I would like to store heart rate registered during a workout (thousands points per training), actually I don’t know what is the best way to store them:

- Create a table with just a HR and time columns linked to a training table
- Store it as JSON in a column of a training table
- Use Postgres Arrays (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), in training table
- Other solutions

That is the same thing to store at a t time the speed for example, or other informations that permit to do a graph with workout stats.

Comment: I'd go with parent-child tables (i.e. your option #1). Why? Because it is **simple**, easy to implement and use.

Comment: It's best to give each datapoint a column so that the database can index the data which makes searching and aggregating faster. Also, time series databases are optimised for storing heaps of time based data (clickhouse, influxdb, timescaledb).